# css, js .htaccess rewrite to a file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following line, but it doesn't seem to work, anyone can tell me where I am going wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css css.php?
```

I have other lines above but I don't believe they are relevent.

But I have another line below that which is about any other file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?
```

so they look like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css css.php?
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?
```

I just need all css request to go through the css.php first then that will return a css file content.

Comment: Paste you entire .htaccess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following rule. All css requests will be directed to `css.php`, all JS requests will be directed to `js.php`. `[L]` means: Last rule, so that later rules do not affect this rule.

I've also added another line, to prevent `index.php` redirecting to `index.php` in an infinite loop.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|js) $2.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php index.php [L] #Prevent infinite loops
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css css.php?$1
```

$1 contains the content from the brackets.

Comment: You should find the name now in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; otherwise test this one: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css css.php?basename=$1`

Comment: the questionmark is just there to provide a force cache refresh kinda thing, it's good practice :)